# Disable Script Debugging in IE is not working in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium with IE7, and my browser settings are configured to: 
1. disable script debugging (Internet explorer) - TRUE 
2. disable script debugging (Other) - TRUE 
3. display a notification about every script error - FALSE 
Also, pop-up blocker is turned on in high filter level. 
I tried *ieploreproxy instead of *iexplore as browser string. The browser is not invoked when I try this.
When running selenium, I am still getting the IE script error pop-up. 
How can I block these pop-ups?

Thanks in advance, 
Sumitra

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Run Selenium RC as administrator:

1. Open cmd.exe as Administrator
2. Type: java -jar selenium.jar